# How to recreate inner shadow in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

I need to create an inner shadow like this, but it's not of a constant width, and it also repeats the corner radius of my shape. What's the best way to do it? And also, I feel pretty constrained with my skills in graphics. What technic should I learn to be able to draw almost anything with Swift?
[image: like this]

Comment: Do you know how to draw a path using something like `UIBezierPath`? You can customize a `CALayer shadowPath` by drawing a custom path.

Comment: You can do all kinds of drawing with Core Graphics, but it's not the most fun API to work with and it can get quite tedious. This isn't really an answer to your question but check out https://www.paintcodeapp.com. It's an app that lets you make pictures and export them to code that can be easily parameterized. You could use that app, or use it just to get an idea of how to draw stuff like this in code.